# Solution set of the two equations is the graph of a smooth map.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Suppose two equations $x + xy + z^2 = 3$ and $x^3 + 2xy − y^2z^2 = 2$ are given. How to show that the solution set of the above two equations is the graph of a smooth map $\gamma : I \to R^2$ in a neighborhood of $(1, 1, 1)$, where $I \subset R$ is open?

Need Hint how to apply Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: This  seems to be an application of the Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem.